# How to check username and password case sensitive?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a login check script that checks if username and password match an account that is set in the database. All works fine but it isn't case sensitive which it really should be! What can I do to make this script also check for uppercase/lowercase? For example: I have an account with username: AdMin password: My43sGG. If I would enter admin and my43sgg in the login fields it would also work.

my script:

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include("config.php");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM " .$members. " WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:index.php");
}
else {
?>
```

Comment: **Don't store passwords in plaintext!** (Or use the old `mysql_` functions, for that matter.) Look into PHPass for password storage and PDO/mysqli for database access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `BINARY`

```
WHERE BINARY username = BINARY '$myusername' AND
      BINARY password = BINARY '$mypassword'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40afb/2)

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I rewrote my query like this: $sql="SELECT * FROM " .$members. " WHERE BINARY username= BINARY '$myusername' and BINARY password= BINARY '$mypassword'"; but that doesn't work.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to work out a solution based on your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not relevant to the question, but it would be better if you AES encrypted the password with itself as the shared secret and looked up the AES encrypted string in the database....I would imagine that would also resolve the issue as well though as they would differ if encrypted with a different case

Comment: Nice idea, but one should really use a hashing algorithm like bcrypt.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have any knowledge about AES encryption though...

Comment: there's a function for that ;) here's bcrypt as suggested by cyberdev 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function to validate it like this

```
function isPartUppercase($string) {
if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $string)===0) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$errorMessage = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['txtUserId']) && isset($_POST['txtPassword'])) { 

    $userId   = $_POST['txtUserId']; 
    $password = ($_POST['txtPassword']); 
     require_once("db_fns.php");
    db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT *  
            FROM adminuser
            WHERE username = '$userId' AND password = '$password'"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error());  

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $admin=$row['username'];
   // print $admin;
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) { 

        $_SESSION['db_is_logged_in'] = true; 

        $_SESSION['admin']=$admin;

        header('Location: main.php'); 
        exit; 
    } else { 
        $errorMessage = 'Sorry, wrong user id / password'; 
    } 

} 
?>
```

Comment: le wild `require_once("db_fns.php");` appears o_o

Comment: This code is vunerable to SQL injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php